# How can I "disable" zoom on a mobile web page?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am creating a mobile web page that is basically a big form with several text inputs.

However (at least on my Android cellphone), every time I click on some input the whole page zooms there, obscuring the rest of the page. Is there some HTML or CSS command to disable this kind of zoom on moble web pages?

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't be disabled for most sites, but there are some use cases where you may want to disable the default zooming - such as mobile web games where you may want to override zooming to do something else.

Comment: For Android Firefox users, there is the [Always Zoom for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/always-zoom/) add-on.  Highly recommended.

Comment: From **iOS 10**, `user-scalable=no` is ignored. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari)

Comment: I am disabling zoom for a canvas project. Zooming could mess up the algorithms behind the animation. I agree, developers must consider usability prior to disabling zoom. Adjust font sizes and page structure accordingly. The `vmin` CSS measurement unit is helpful here. I also recommend using percentages and `vh` and `vw`.

Comment: We use a chromium browser control for our kiosk desktop application. If users can do pinch zoom it can get us in lots of troubles. Unfortunately the solutions below didn't work for me, and now I am trying to use --disable-pinch command.

Comment: I created a website for myself and myself only. Nobody other than me is going to use it. I want zoom disabled. If  developers out there disable zooming when they should not - why am I supposed to pay the price for their mistakes?

Answer (score 615):

This should be everything you need:

```
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Comment: this also disables the user's ability to zoom in general, as well as the browser's ability to auto-adjust the way the page fits into the viewport - all Martin is looking for is a way to disable the 'zoom-on-input-click' behavior.

Comment: I agree with matt. This doesn't really answer the question, what if I want to have zoom enabled in general, just not on input focus...?

Comment: Right now someone at Posterous did just that, while having the font at 12px so it's unreadable and I cannot find a way around it.

Comment: Only the first line. And move name="viewport" to the line's beginning.

Comment: Every visually impaired person, including myself, hates this more than anything. I have to take screen grabs of pages that do this and then zoom in on them in the picture viewer.

Comment: What does the second meta tag do? Isn't the `width=device-width` already in the first meta tag?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on iOS 7. See lukad03 answer

Comment: For iOS7 too, replace user-scalable=0 with user-scalable=no.

Comment: It can be better to change the text-size. Have a look at this website: http://www.jonassebastianohlsson.com/blog/2013/11/25/how-to-stop-zoom-in-on-input-focus-on-mobile-devices/

Comment: For anyone searching this issue now, this worked for me. It does not affect my browser version at all and disables zoom completely in my mobile version. As well as the annoying zoom when you focus on an input. (ios 9+)

Comment: @JackMarchetti, surely there must be an browser extension to override this. I work a lot with maps where zooming within map vs. within page is really tough to solve neatly in any other way.

Comment: @Henrik - what I ended up doing was creating a bookmark in mobile safari that removes this line of code using javascript.  Setting user scale to zero has been less of a problem in recent years.

Comment: (to everyone who thinks disabling zoom is a bad idea) For games, I really don't expect people to need to zoom into the 40px text of the buttons.

Comment: iOS has a zoom feature on the OS level. There's no need to have it in the webview for things like apps which are trying to have a similar experience to native apps.

Answer (score 200):

For those of you late to the party, kgutteridge's answer doesn't work for me and Benny Neugebauer's answer includes target-densitydpi (a [feature that is being deprecated](http://petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/viewport-target-densitydpi-support-is-being-deprecated/)).

This however does work for me:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: This is the correct answer now. The other answers no longer work (at least for iOS 7).

Comment: Anyone tried this on iOS 10.x I don't think it's working?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It resized all the screen with scrollbar and bad zoom.

Comment: Still not working on Safari/iOS 11 due to the SFB issue at Apple.

Comment: Literally no difference between the two answers.

Comment: There is a small difference - kgutteridge's answer has `user-scalable=0` instead of `user-scalable=no`. What difference it makes I'm not sure.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Google Chrome on iPhone

Answer (score 76):

There are a number of approaches here- and though the position is that ***typically users should not be restricted*** when it comes to zooming for accessibility purposes, there may be incidences where is it required:

**Render the page at the width of the device, dont scale:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**Prevent scaling- and prevent the user from being able to zoom:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

**Removing all zooming, all scaling**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Comment: "typically users should not be restricted" but when developing web apps for mobile you often have to deal with the "zom-in on input focus". I find it helpful to disable zooming in that case.

Comment: @Le'nton disabling zooming on the entire page is not a good way to deal with zoom in on input focus. On iOS at least, input focus zoom can be disabled by increasing the font size of the input.

Comment: `when developing web apps for mobile you often have to deal with the "zom-in on input focus"` This is not something to deal with but the app should be designed to work together with this feature. This kind of features were specifically designed to improve user experience (UX) and are based on best practices to help users.

Comment: "typically users should not be restricted"
I have never seen a mobile app that lets you zoom. Why should mobile web apps be different? Provided you are using rem units appropriately, the user can simply increase the font size on their device.

Comment: @user3044394 because most of the people that say it shouldn't be a thing because they themselves have never had a niche case where this would make sense. It's an option for a reason. They're just being ignorant.

Comment: @user3044394 Pinch-to-zoom, along with other nice features like tabs, saving images, copying text, bookmarks, the reload button, etc., make web apps a lot better than native apps!  Native mobile apps are good for gaming, using an app offline, and anything else is extremely niche.

Comment: @hegel5000 If the user has to zoom to see something, then your app is not WCAG 2.0 compliant as required by the Americans with Disabilities Act. WCAG 2.0 Specifically calls this out. You shouldn't need to zoom. There should also never be scrolling on both x/y axis, which zooming would break that rule too.

Comment: @user3044394 I doubt that there is web infrastructure with the psionic aptitude necessary to tell anyone wants to zoom or not . . . other than just letting users zoom when they want to.  In any case my point is that just because many native mobile apps don't have nice features doesn't mean you need to make web apps worse just to match.

Comment: @hegel5000 It's not web infrastructure. It's common law. Two corporations I have worked for were sued because of it. They did no care at all before the lawsuits. They suddenly cared very much so after losing millions and several managers were fired in both cases. Take that as you will.

Comment: @user3044394 I do get the importance of WCAG!  It's great regardless of ability: the curb cut effect and all that.  It requires the option for regular old text resizing (which doesn't require horizontal scrolling) alongside already large (no more than 80 characters per line) text if requested.  It doesn't require that pinch to zoom also be disabled, though.

Comment: There's no way to design an app to suit most people automatically, not without giving them options, hence my joke about "psionic aptitude".  WCAG gets that.

Comment: @hegel5000 your user should not need to zoom if you simply give rem units to all your font sizes and rem scaling to all of your UI elements. They can adjust the scale of everything by increasing or decreasing their font size. There's literally no reason to zoom.

Comment: @user3044394 Zooming helps with highlighting and copying, text, with hitting the intended link, with looking at images . . .

Comment: You can achieve the same effect as zooming by allowing the user to scale your UI. It also looks a lot better and is a lot more accessible.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about that.  Most websites which disable pinch to zoom don't let me do that, though :(

Comment: Tell a friend who wears glasses to sue them and collect money *shrug* lol

Comment: IIRC every time a business entity is sued under ADA, there's also a minimum fine/penalty. That penalty doubles with every instance. So if they get sued multiple times the fine will keep doubling.

Answer (score 71):

Seems like just adding meta tags to index.html doesn't prevent page from zooming. Adding below style will do the magic.

```
:root {
  touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
  height: 100% 
}
```

EDIT:
Demo: https://no-mobile-zoom.stackblitz.io

Comment: This should be accepted fix , also working on mobile safari ios13 atm

Comment: It's working as expected from mobile, thanks! check here https://proyecto26.com/animatable-component/

Comment: I had to use html as my selector. :root did not work on iOS 13 for me, but html did. PS, the EDIT: Demo link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: WOW this works so well. Thank you for posting this.

Comment: best solution, works for me perfectly... with HTML tag in CSS on mobile media query

Comment: @neveraskedforthis did you just use html { touch-action: pan-x pan-y; height: 100% }

Comment: If you I to zoom very I still can on my site, on the example site i can't :) ios 14.5 iphone 12 pro max

Comment: I applied touch-action: pan-x pan-y; just to a div of buttons, not the whole page. Prevents zoom if the user slightly missed the button!

Comment: This one was the only working solution for me. Using and iPhone SE. Thanks

Answer (score 54):

**Mobile browsers (most of them) require font-size in inputs to be 16px.**

And since there is still no solution for initial issue, here's a pure CSS solution.

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="password"] {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

solves the issue. So you don't need to disable zoom and loose accessibility features of you site.

If your base font-size is not 16px or not 16px on mobiles, you can use media queries.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  input[type="text"],
  input[type="number"],
  input[type="email"],
  input[type="tel"],
  input[type="password"] {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does this solution have so few votes? It's by far the best way to avoid form-click zooming.

Comment: Yes; this solved my problem as well!  I didn't want to disable zooming entirely and this was just what I needed.

Comment: You can also set `font-size: 1rem` for the whole page, so the font scales nicely, simultaneously avoiding "focus-on-zoom" problem.

Comment: @KlausCPH Because it restricts you to have 16px, that's too huge for my website. Using user-scalable=0 is enough nowadays. The zoom is still possible on modern browsers for accessibility.

Answer (score 44):

You can use:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  ...
</head>
```

But please note that with **Android 4.4** the property [target-densitydpi is no longer supported](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#TargetDensity). So for Android 4.4 and later the following is suggested as best practice:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My site is still scaleable in FF on android.

Answer (score 17):

please try adding this meta-tag and style

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>


<style>
body{
        touch-action: manipulation;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: shouldn't `touch-action` be set to `none` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action#Values

Comment: @rahulroy9202 for me `touch-action: manipulation;` worked fine. `touch-action: none;` didnt do anything

Comment: This didn't work for me on Google Chrome on iPhone

Answer (score 12):

Possible Solution for Web Apps: While zooming can not be disabled in iOS Safari anymore,
**it will be disabled when opening the site from a home screen shortcut.**

Add these meta tags to declare your App as "Web App capable":

```html
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" >
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" >
```

However **only** use this feature if your app is self sustaining, as the forward/backward buttons and URL bar as well as the sharing options are disabled. (You can still swipe left and right though) This approach however enables quite the app like ux. The fullscreen browser only starts when the site is loaded from the homescreen. <s>I also only got it to work after I included an apple-touch-icon-180x180.png in my root folder.</s>

As a bonus, you probably also want to include a variant of this as well:

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
  if (event.scale !== 1) { event.preventDefault(); }
}, { passive: false });
</script>
```

Please Add the Script to Disable  pinch, tap, focus Zoom

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me on iPad. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me!!! Google Chrome on iPhone!!!

Answer (score 5):

```
<header>
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
</header>
```

A pure `"user-scalable=no"` is sufficient and excluding other width and scale parameters should be fine for your case. In my case, I have just simply added the snippet on my . Tested on iOS 16.

Comment: This makes any zooming and scrollbars not scalable. Everything is in birdview when running scrollbars on desktop

Comment: @Bitdom8 Not true for modern browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish the task by simply adding the following 'meta' element into your 'head':

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

Adding all the attributes like 'width','initial-scale', 'maximum-width', 'maximum-scale' might not work. Therefore, just add the above element.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using a `meta`-tag did not work for me (tested on Chrome win10 and safari IOS 14.3), and I also believe that the concerns regarding accessibility, as mentioned by Jack and others, should be honored.

My solution is to disable zooming only on elements that are damaged by the default zoom.

I did this by registering event listeners for zoom-gestures and using `event.preventDefault()` to suppress the browsers default zoom-behavior.

This needs to be done with several events (touch gestures, mouse wheel and keys). The following snippet is an example for the mouse wheel and pinch gestures on touchpads:

```
noteSheetCanvas.addEventListener("wheel", e => {
        // suppress browsers default zoom-behavior:
        e.preventDefault();

        // execution of my own custom zooming-behavior:
        if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            this._zoom(1);
        } else {
            this._zoom(-1);
        }
    });
```

How to detect touch gestures is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11183333/1134856

I used this to keep the standard zooming behavior for most parts of my application and to define custom zooming-behavior on a canvas-element.

Answer (score 0):

Using this post and a few others I managed to sort this out so that is compatible with Android and iPhone/iPad/iPod using the following code. This is for PHP, you can use the same concept for any other language with string searches.

```
<?php //Device specific headers
$iPod    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iPhone  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$iPad    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$Android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$webOS   = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");

if($iPhone || $iPod || $iPad){
    echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />';
} else {
    echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />';
}
```

?>

Answer (score -1):

This may help someone: on iOS, my problem was fixed by swapping `<button>`s for `<div>`s, along with the other things mentioned.

Answer (score -3):

```
document.addEventListener('dblclick', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer a bit more. We claim to be a reference book, i.e. the solutions should be explained.

Comment: Zoom in web page become from double click on the same point of the page .
If you prevent default double click you will prevent zoom.

This method works on ios(android must be too, havent tested yet).