# Disable pinch to zoom in IE10

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer-10, gestures

In IE10 touch mode I wish to make only a certain part of the page zoomable. The rest should not be.

I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/hh772044.aspx and tried to set `-ms-touch-action: none` to my `body` and `html` tags.

However I can still zoom. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found the solution: `-ms-content-zooming: none | zoom`

Comment: asked yourself, answered yourself. what can be better? voting up

Comment: Also this work in the same way in webkit browser using: -webkit-content-zooming or content-zooming

Answer (score 6):

For me this CSS code work

```
html {

      -ms-content-zooming: none;
      -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y;

}
```

I am using this code for disabling pinch and double tap zoom on windows tablet, I.E 10

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your Head area:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```