# Disable default pinch to zoom in Chrome on Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, mobile

There are a lot of questions how to disable pinch to zoom and there are a lot of good answers. What I learned from questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11689353/498298) and what I'm using in my app is:

```
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">


html, body {
  -ms-content-zooming: none;
  touch-action: none;   
}
```

This works well for IE11 and on Chrome for most cases. But there is at least one special case, where Chrome on a MS Surface with Windows 8.1 starts to zoom: Pinch on a `div` that has `overflow: auto`. Is this a known issue? Is there any solution to this problem (I can't find)?

A Javascript solution is not a problem, since I already handle touch events to implement different touch gestures (like a custom zoom action).
I could call `event.preventDefault()` in my touch event handlers but this disables the default scroll gestures as well.