Zoom Video stream on Mobile Browser While using getUserMedia
I am using getUserMedia in my web page to open user's camera and then capture image from the video stream. On Desktop it works fine, but on mobile devices, the pinch zoom zooms in the entire web page, I want only the video element to be zoomed in and when I capture the image, the zoomed image should be captured on canvas. Below is my code:
const startCamera = (facingMode?: string | { exact: string }) => {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      let facingModeSupported = true;
      if (
        navigator.mediaDevices &&
        navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints &&
        facingMode
      ) {
        const supports = navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints();
        if (!supports['facingMode']) {
          facingModeSupported = false;
        }
      }
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: false,
          video: facingModeSupported && facingMode
            ? {
                facingMode: facingMode ? facingMode : 'user',
              }
            : true,
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          streamTracks.current = stream;
          if (cameraVideoStream.current) {
            cameraVideoStream.current.srcObject = stream;
            cameraVideoStream.current.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
              if (cameraVideoStream.current) {
                cameraVideoStream.current.play();
              }
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
        });
    }
  };

Below is the Code to Capture the Image:
if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvasContext = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
      if (canvasContext && cameraVideoStream.current) {
        canvasRef.current.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvasRef.current.height = window.innerHeight;
        const videoAspect =
          cameraVideoStream.current.videoWidth /
          cameraVideoStream.current.videoHeight;
        const canvasAspect = canvasRef.current.width / canvasRef.current.height;
        let renderWidth,
          renderHeight,
          offsetX = 0,
          offsetY = 0;
        if (videoAspect > canvasAspect) {
          renderHeight = canvasRef.current.height;
          renderWidth = renderHeight * videoAspect;
          offsetX = -(renderWidth - canvasRef.current.width) / 2;
        } else {
          renderWidth = canvasRef.current.width;
          renderHeight = renderWidth / videoAspect;
          offsetY = -(renderHeight - canvasRef.current.height) / 2;
        }
        if (cameraMode === 'front') {
          canvasContext.translate(window.innerWidth, 0);
          canvasContext.scale(-1, 1);
        }
        canvasContext?.drawImage(
          cameraVideoStream.current,
          0,
          0,
          cameraVideoStream.current.videoWidth,
          cameraVideoStream.current.videoHeight,
          offsetX,
          offsetY,
          renderWidth,
          renderHeight
        );
        const data = canvasRef.current.toDataURL('image/png');
        stopCamera();
      }
    }


This question doesn't really have to do with capturing video or anything like that.  You just need to override the pinch/zoom behavior with your own.

How can I do that? If I pinch zoom on the screen, the entire web page zooms, I need only the video stream to zoom

Check out some of the responses here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201924/362536
