# Bootstrap responsive 2 does not load on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, responsive-design

I have a responsive WP theme based on a Bootstrap ver2 css framework. Everything works on desktop: if test in different size (for different media queries) no problem. But if I'm testing on phone doesn't loads the media query. What could be the problem.

Link to the site: http://moldovan.szanto-zoltan.com/

p.s.: the header contains this to fit the device width

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

### Via the documentation of Bootstrap 2

> Bootstrap doesn't include responsive features by default at this time
>   as not everything needs to be responsive. Instead of encouraging
>   developers to remove this feature, we figure it best to enable it as
>   needed.

### How to enabling responsive features

> Turn on responsive CSS in your project by including the proper meta
>   tag and additional stylesheet within the **`<head>`** of your document. If
>   you've compiled Bootstrap from the Customize page, you need only
>   include the meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

### If you don't compiled Bootstrap from the Customize page,  here is how to do it

1. Use the compiled responsive version, bootstrap-responsive.css
2. Add @import "responsive.less" and recompile Bootstrap
3. Modify and recompile responsive.less as a separate file

.

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

for more information, read the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive). I hope this solution will help you.

#### Suggestion

I think the best solution is to use bootstrap 3 it will work fine

Add those meta in your header page to tell the browser to disable the scaling. Then the CSS @media selectors are working as expected :

```
<meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

suggestion from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021794/android-browser-ignores-responsive-web-design)

Comment: Hi, I think the best solution is to use bootstrap 3 it will work fine

Comment: on desktop Firefox/Chrome works (even if i change the browser width to a mobile width) the problem comes when I'm looking the page in android browser (if I install Firefox on android works perfectly) or on iOS safari. any idea?

Comment: Still no luck, but now I noticed that in Safari doesn't works (not even desktop version, but on chrome & ff works great)

Comment: looks fine your website if you test it in [responsinator](http://www.responsinator.com/), so I think the problem is the Bootstrap 2 and browser's phone, I'm really sorry. Hope you find a solution

Comment: I figured out something, if I change the container class to container-fluid it works, just the container isn't centered. I think this could be the problem

Comment: Great, look this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184141/how-do-you-get-centered-content-using-twitter-bootstrap)