# disable webview zoom in App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

When I create an app with **App Inventor** and I add a `webviewer` component, it appears an annoying icon to zoom.
Wonder how can I disable this icon.

If there isn't a specific function implemented in App Inventor, please tell me which part of the java code I have to modify.
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally you can't disable the zoom for the `webviewer` component in **App Inventor**.

In case you are displaying your own webpages, you can try to add the following into your HTML header tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472910/1545993

Probably this will not work for older Android versions...

Comment: Works great in Oreo. To use in PHP scripts, add echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"> ';

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setDisplayZoomControls` for disabling the zoom controls UI :

```
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: where I have to put that? Is setDisplayZoomControls an app invetor feature? Or I have to modifie the java file?

Comment: You need to add it in java file