# How do I disable zoom in or out web page in mobile view?

Tags: html

I have used viewport meta tag to fit the web page for mobile view. But now I want to disable zoom in or zoom out of web page.

Comment: You just want to disable the zoom on mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

But I think your question duplicate with:

[How can I "disable" zoom on a mobile web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page)