# Iphone automatically zooms in on <select> tag

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, reactjs

I have a webapp that I am trying out on my phone, and everytime I try to click on the select tag, it zooms in, and then I have to manually zoom it out, which isn't the end of the world but its kind of annoying. I read that

```
select{
  font-size: 16px;
}
select:focus{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

should solve the issue, but I tried that and the issue persisted. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this meta tag to the head of your document to prevent zooming on mobile:

```
<meta 
    name='viewport' 
    content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' 
/>
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472910/2590203