# How can I prevent my site's width from expanding on the phone?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

my site works good on the desktop and now I'm working on the phone responsiveness (I know that's not how you're supposed to do it, and I can really see why now! X)) Anyway, the layout is fine and I just checked by making my window a smaller screen. However I actually checked on phones and there's a problem. The width is expanding more than it needs to 
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr0cD.png). Therefore, everything is off centered and so on...How can I fix this?

```css
::root {
  --background: pink;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(black,#941313);
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
}
/* nav bar styles start here */

 header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
     background-color: black;
   text-align: center;
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
/*z-index:999;*/
     top: 0;
   }
nav {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  transform: scale(1,0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out; 
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
     list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-family: 'Raleway','sans-serif';
}
nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #941313;
}
.nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}
.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
 transform: scale(1,1);
}
.nav-toggle-label {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-toggle-label span,
.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  height: 2px;
  width: 2em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
.nav-toggle-label span::before {
  bottom: 7px;
}
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  top: 7px; 
}
.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav a {
  opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

/*FOR LARGER SCREENS */
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .nav-toggle-label {
    display: none;
  }

  header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr;
    top:0;
   /* height: 120px;*/
  }
  header::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  
  .logo {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  
  nav {
    padding-left: 10px;
   all: unset; /* this causes issues with Edge, since it's unsupported */
    
    /* the following lines are not from my video, but add Edge support */
   position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    transition: none;
    transform: scale(1,1);
    background: none;
    top: initial;
    left: initial;
    /* end Edge support stuff */
    
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center; 
  }
  
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  nav li {
   /* margin-left: 3em;*/
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 60px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 2px;
   position: relative;
  }
  
  nav a {
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 7px;
    background: #941313;
    position: absolute;
    top: -.75em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
    /*transition: transform ease-in-out 250ms;*/
  }
  
  nav a:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}
  /*INTRO AND CIRCLES */

  .intro h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Raleway", "";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-top: 175px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 120px;
  }
  .links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .links h1 {
    font-family: "Raleway", " ";
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .circles {
    color: white;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: black;
    position: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #c60c30;
  }
  .circles h1 {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .circles a {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    color: white;
  }
  .circles a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .links {
      display: inline-block;
      justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .circles {
  
      display: inline-block;
      
    }
  }


/*YOUNG CANADIAN"S SAYING*/
.about-image {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.resist {
  background-image: url(img/bg02.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 #000;
}
.overlay {
font-family: "Raleway", "";
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
  height: 5%;
  }
  
  .overlay a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Raleway", "";
  text-align: left;
  }
  
  .overlay a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: linear .4s;
  }
  .further h1{
    padding-top: 20px;
font-family: 'Raleway','sans-serif';
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;

  }
  .further h2 {
    font-family: 'Raleway','sans-serif';
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
  /*LARGE SCREENS*/
  @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .all {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .about-image {
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-right: 120px;
    }
.further h1 {
padding-left: 100px;
}
.further h2 {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
  }
   

  /*ABOUT PAGE */
    /*ABOUT PAGE */
 .whole {
  padding-top: 175px;
  padding-left: 80px;
 }
  .whole h1 {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .whole p {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .profile_img {
    float: right;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #941313;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .ready {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .profile_img {
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .ready {
      display: inline;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
    }
  }
  
  .join {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  .join-button {
    background: black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 #941313;
    color: white;
  }
  .join-button:hover {
    background: #941313;
    color: white;

  }
  .join-button a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Raleway", 'times new roman';
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 black;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .whole {
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
    .profile_img {
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }

 /*CONTACT*/

 .parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("img/joinus.gif");

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.button  {
  color: white;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: black;
    position: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #c60c30;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 
}

.btn lightbox-201405305051235 {
  color: white;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: black;
    position: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #c60c30;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 
}

.button h1 {
  font-family:'Raleway','serif';
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #941313;
}

.button:hover {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: heartbeat 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both;
            animation: heartbeat 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both;
  
}
/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-6-10 21:41:58
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation heartbeat
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
 @-webkit-keyframes heartbeat {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
            transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.91);
            transform: scale(0.91);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  17% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.98);
            transform: scale(0.98);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.87);
            transform: scale(0.87);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
@keyframes heartbeat {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
            transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.91);
            transform: scale(0.91);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  17% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.98);
            transform: scale(0.98);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.87);
            transform: scale(0.87);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}


.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .9);
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.modal__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-state {
  display: none;
}

.modal-state:checked + .modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-state:checked + .modal .modal__inner {
  top: 0;
}

.modal__inner {
  transition: top .25s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  height: 80%;
}

.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal__close:after,
.modal__close:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin: -3px 0 0 -1px;
  top: 0;
}

.modal__close:hover:after,
.modal__close:hover:before {
  background: #aaa;
}

.modal__close:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.submit-app {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.submit-app:hover {
  color: #941313;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    
  .modal__inner {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: -20%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .box {
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .button {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

  /*FOOTER*/ 
  .footer {
    width: 100vw;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
  }
  .inner_footer {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .inner_footer .logo_container {
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    
  }
  .inner_footer .logo_container img{
    width: 100px; 
    height: auto;
  }
  .inner_footer .footer_third {
    width: calc(21.66666667% - 20px);
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%
  }
  .inner_footer .footer_third:last-child {
    margin-right: 0; 
  }
  .inner_footer .footer_third h1 {
    font-family: "Raleway", "times new roman";
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .inner_footer .footer_third a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Raleway", "times new roman";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 200;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    /*text-transform: lowercase;*/
     
  }
  .inner_footer .footer_third a:hover {
    color: #941313;
    transition: ease .6s;
  }
  .inner_footer .footer_third li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .inner_footer .footer_third span {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
.newsletter-form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .email p {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
   .txtb {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 18px 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    min-width: 260px;
 }
 input .btn {
   font-family: 'Raleway',serif;
   color: black;
   font-size: 100px;
   width: 20px;
   height: 10px;
   background-color: grey;

 }
 .btn:hover{
color: #941313;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .footer .inner_footer {
     width: 90%;
   }
   .inner_footer .logo_container,
 .inner_footer .footer_third {
     width: 100%;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
   }
 }
 /* Turn off parallax scrolling for all tablets and phones. Increase/decrease the pixels if needed */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) {
  .parallax {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please try to include some html code also or make a jsfiddle/codepen replicating the issue you are facing, it will help the community users to better understand the issue and help you, Thank you.

Comment: Also make sure the `html` code has this `meta` tag in the `<head>` section `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

Include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
 and use `100vw` for width instead of 100% or _px... **vw** is the expression which is used to define dimensions according to the view port, basically, it will set the width taking a percentage ratio from the view port or the device's width.
 You can check other sites for achieving a mobile responsive website...

In your case the problem can also be caused by zooming out the web page as it distorts the complete layout in some devices (mainly Ios)... 
you can search for some answer that answers on [how to disable pinch zoom on mobile web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page)

Please let me know if problem still remains!!
Regards,
Om Chaudhary

Answer (score 0):

use the CSS attribute for the container element

```
 .mycontainer{
max-width:100vw;
}
```