# React Select input zoom -- can't disable on iPhone XS

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone

I have the following code for a React dropdown:

```
import Select from 'react-select';

const dropdownStyles = {
  control: base => ({
    ...base,
    fontSize: '1.8vh'
  }),
  menu: base => ({
    ...base,
    fontSize: '1.8vh'
  }),
}

...

<Select
  className="dropdown-select"
  styles={dropdownStyles}
  options={this.options()}
  defaultValue={this.options()[0]}
  onChange={selection =>
    this.setState({'type': selection.value})
  } />
```

On my iPhone XS, in both Chrome and Safari, it zooms in when I press the dropdown to select a value.

I have tried multiple different solutions to get rid of this, based on other StackOverflow answers.  I've added a meta tag to the page header to prevent zooming.  I've manipulated the fontSize passed in to ensure it's greater than 16px.  I've added a CSS rule for `.Select input` to change the font-size.  Nothing worked.

Is there something unique about iPhone XS that breaks the solutions that worked before?

Comment: maybe try different meta tags from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page)? I mean are you sure you have the correct meta tag?

Comment: Yeah neither <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> nor the version with user-scalable set to 0 did anything.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the similar problem with this scenario. If the font size you are using on react-select dropdown is < 16px then iOS will zoom to that input field. That is for accessibility reasons.

You can use something like this:

```
.dropdown-select__control.dropdown-select__control--is-focused {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

and it should fix your problem.

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Comment: This is already mentioned in the question, but thanks for spelling it out. Do you have an iPhone XS and were able to fix the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using

```css
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
 .dropdown-select:focus, .dropdown-select .select__control input:focus {
     font-size: 1.8vh;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check `react-select` website on your device. Check if the dropdown there is also zooming up on your phone?

Comment: Those examples do not have the issue.

Comment: I'm also using `react-select` and `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />` this inside `<head>` of index.html woked for me

Comment: Can you check if the meta tag is there, after building the bundle. i.e `build` folder