# How to stop pinch zoom on a laptop pad using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gesture, pinchzoom

Can anyone please tell me that is it possible to stop pinch zoom from laptop mouse pad using javascript/jquery in browser? If yes then how it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I "disable" zoom on a mobile web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page)

Comment: I tested every answer on the post Justinas has linked, any of the answers doesn't prevent pinching on a laptop touchpad to zoom a page. It's also extremely poor UX, dont't prevent zooming on your pages.